# Crystal reports not pulling same data as sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I have the following code:

```
select order_number,received_date
from order_head
where order_head.order_number not in (select order_number from csa_log group by order_number)
and ordernature in ('02','03')
and received_date > '01.01.2010'
and buyer_code = 'GAP'
group by order_number,received_date
order by received_date desc
```

When run in crystal reports does not pull the same data as sql server express. It is pulling only one record as opposed to 7.  Anybody have some insight?  Thank you in advance.  (I have a suspicion it has something to do with the nested statement).

Comment: Did you create a command in Crystal or you are building the select statement using crystal UI?

Comment: Something that I usually do in Crystal is select Database from the menu and then select Show SQL Statement and copy the select statement that Crystal is creating.

Comment: I did that and it's the same sql.

Comment: Did you check that the select records conditions is empty? What Crystal Version are you using?

Comment: Are you using any parameters in the command like {?Date} or something like it?

Comment: I am trying to check that but since I am not familiar I'm having some trouble.  I am on v10.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for all records > '01.01.10'

Comment: Three more things to check to narrow down the problem:
- Check at the bottom right of the preview the numbers of records that Crystal says it retrieved.
- Double check that you are not getting one row per page. (When you do not show the item in the detail it will show you just the first item )
- Remove the nested statement from the where to check if you get the same number of rows that you are getting in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use SQL server profiler to check what SQL Statements Crystal is running behind the scenes. In your case is not possible because you are running SQL Server Express.

In Crystal you have the option of checking the actual SQL statement that Crystal is running by selecting "Database" and "Show SQL Statement" in the top menu.

Make sure that under Reports menu you are not putting any conditions in the Select Records.

Check that you are showing the fields in the detail and not in the header or footer. That is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilites come to mind.

First are you absolutely sure that Crystal Reports and the database you are querying are the same one. Amazing how often one is querying dev and another prod when you have these kinds of issues. Even if you don't believe this to be the case, check this anyway.

Permissions could be another reason for the discrepancy.

Finally confirm that the two queries are exactly the same. Use Profiler if possible to confirm this.